# Convert a string like "01:53:23.123 "from attributes into milliseconds using only analyze-string, the if-then-else and let expression with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

My problem is that I need to convert strings from attributes `<pc:episode duration="01:23:23">)` into milliseconds using the if-then-else Expression(if no hour or minute is used in the string then then else...) I hope my question is clear.

Here is an example XML-Code (which I have posted before in another question):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<pc:podcast
    xmlns:pc="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast/0.3"
    xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast/0.3
        podcast.xsd
        https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1
        podcast-transcript.xsd"
    url="https://forschergeist.de/"
    version="0.3">

    <pc:title>Forschergeist</pc:title>

    <pc:persons>
        <pc:person pid="timpritlove" gender="male">Tim Pritlove</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="ritaadrian" gender="female">Rita Adrian</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="peterpurgathofer" gender="male">Peter Purgathofer</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="justushaucap" gender="male">Justus Haucap</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="oliverparodi" gender="male">Oliver Parodi</pc:person>
        <pc:person pid="alinakokoschka" gender="female">Alina Kokoschka</pc:person>
    </pc:persons>

    <pc:episode episode="73" title="Klimawandel in Seen" date="2019-11-19T19:35:00" url="https://forschergeist.de/podcast/fg073-klimawandel-in-seen/" duration="01:23:14">
        <pc:contributor pid="timpritlove" role="host"/>
        <pc:contributor pid="ritaadrian" role="guest" />

        <pc:chapter number="1" duration="00:41" title="Intro" />
        <pc:chapter number="2" duration="01:14" title="Begrüßung" />
        <pc:chapter number="3" duration="04:41" title="Leibniz-Institut für Gewässerökologie und Binnenfischerei " />
        <pc:chapter number="4" duration="02:35" title="Persönlicher Werdegang" />
        <pc:chapter number="5" duration="04:44" title="Wissenschaftskultur in den USA" />
        <pc:chapter number="6" duration="06:34" title="Das Ökosystem der Binnenseen" />
        <pc:chapter number="7" duration="15:04" title="Langzeitbeobachtung der Seen" />
        <pc:chapter number="8" duration="12:46" title="Erkenntnisse aus den Messungen" />
        <pc:chapter number="9" duration="08:27" title="Veränderungen durch den Klimawandel" />
        <pc:chapter number="10" duration="03:10" title="Erforderliche Maßnahmen" />
        <pc:chapter number="11" duration="11:52" title="Wissenschaftliche Arbeit im IPCC" />
        <pc:chapter number="12" duration="10:02" title="Datenmanagement" />
        <pc:chapter number="13" duration="01:06" title="Ausklang" />

        <pt:transcript 
            xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1"
            version="0.1">
        </pt:transcript>
    </pc:episode>

    <pc:episode episode="72" title="Verantwortung in der Informatik" date="2019-10-01T11:00:00" url="https://forschergeist.de/podcast/fg072-verantwortung-in-der-informatik/" duration="01:53:23">
        <pc:contributor pid="timpritlove" role="host"/>
        <pc:contributor pid="peterpurgathofer" role="guest" />

        <pc:chapter number="1" duration="00:42" title="Intro" />
        <pc:chapter number="2" duration="00:46" title="Begrüßung" />
        <pc:chapter number="3" duration="08:26" title="Peter Purgathofer" />
        <pc:chapter number="4" duration="09:26" title="Ethik und Moral in der Informatik" />
        <pc:chapter number="5" duration="06:41" title="Entscheidung und Verantwortung" />
        <pc:chapter number="6" duration="11:22" title="Denkweisen in der Informatik" />
        <pc:chapter number="7" duration="00:55" title="Strukturierung des Kurses" />
        <pc:chapter number="8" duration="05:31" title="Pre-Scientific Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="9" duration="04:15" title="Scientific Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="10" duration="06:01" title="Mathematical Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="11" duration="07:35" title="Computational Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="12" duration="09:57" title="Design Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="13" duration="10:20" title="Critical Thinking und Diversity" />
        <pc:chapter number="14" duration="05:15" title="Responsible Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="15" duration="04:00" title="Creative Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="16" duration="02:18" title="Economical Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="17" duration="04:07" title="Criminal Thinking" />
        <pc:chapter number="18" duration="02:07" title="Denkweisen für die Wissenschaft" />
        <pc:chapter number="19" duration="11:45" title="Der Reifegrad der Informatik" />
        <pc:chapter number="20" duration="01:43" title="Ausklang" />
  </pc:episode> 
    </pc:podcast>
```

for example I want to convert it like this:

```
0.444 → 444 (0 * 1000 + 0.444 * 1000)
12.23 → 12230 (12 * 1000 + 0.23 * 1000 + 0.0 * 1000)
12:46 → 766.000 (12 * 60 * 1000 + 46 * 1000 + 0.0 * 1000)
01:53:23 → 6803000 (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + 53 * 60 * 1000 + 23 * 1000 + 0.0 * 1000)
01:53:23.123 → 6803123 (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + 53 * 60 * 1000 + 23 * 1000 + 0.123 * 1000)
```

so for example if I have a string like 12:46 I want to convert it like mentioned above using the if-then-else expression. If the string is 12:46 then 12:46 → 766.000 (12 * 60 * 1000 + 46 * 1000 + 0.0 * 1000) else if 01:53:23  then 01:53:23.123 → 6803123 (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + 53 * 60 * 1000 + 23 * 1000 + 0.123 * 1000). I must use analyze-string and let.

Here is my approach:

```
let $string :=analyze-string(string(//pc:episode[1]/@duration), '(([0-9]?[0-9]:)?([0-5]?[0-9]:))?([0-5]?[0-9])(\.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)?' ) return xs:integer($string[1])*3600000 + xs:integer($string[2])*60000 + xs:decimal($string[3] || '.' || $string[4])*1000
```

However this does not seem to work. Furthermore I need the if-then-else expression:

Like:

```
if(string(//pc:episode[1]/@duration) != '00:00:00') then only convert the seconds into milliseconds else convert like above.
```

I think I found a possible solution albeit it's not what I looked for:

```
if(string(//pc:episode[1]/@duration) = "([0-9]?[0-9]:)?([0-5]?[0-9]:))?([0-5]?[0-9])(\.[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?)?") then 'error' else let $string1:=string(//pc:episode[1]/@duration), $string :=tokenize($string1, ':') return xs:integer($string[1])*3600000 + xs:integer($string[2])*60000 + xs:decimal($string[3] || '.' || $string[4])*1000
```

Comment: Please explain why you are constrained to use a particular subset of the XPath language.

Comment: More specifically, I can think of lots of good solutions to this problem that don't involve let, analyze-string, or if-then-else - why are such solutions not acceptable?

Comment: @MichaeI Kay I could also use the tokenize function but according to my exercise it is recommonded to use the analyze-string function.

Comment: Start simple, if you want to use `analyze-string` with a regular expression and don't know how to process its result then first look at its result. It is not clear why you think that binding the result of the `analyze-string` call to a variable and then using positional predicates makes any sense, the result is a single element, see https://www.altova.com/xpath-xquery-reference/fn-analyze-string for instance.

Comment: Can I store the match groups into variables and how?

Comment: It appears that the real goal of this exercise is to acquire familiarity with particular constructs in the language. If you have specific questions about how those constructs behave, feel free to ask, but meanwhile, SO is about answering questions, not about developing your skills and competencies.

Comment: I understand that analyze string returns me a single element. But I want to store all the matches for example <group nr.="1">01:</group> into a single varible and then do the calculation to convert hours minutes into milliseconds.

Comment: I figured it out however I need an if else expression. Howcan I do this? I can't figure it out it seems.

Comment: Can you say me how I can use fn:match with regular expression in an if statement?